# R: SQLite query for difference between two date columns in minutes

Tags: r

I have a CSV file having Start date and end date as below. I need a SQLite syntax query which can be used in R, to find the difference between end date and start date and the output should be in mins. Where condition should be Action code = "WO Cancelled" and Minutesdiff <=5.

```
WO Create Date  WO Close Date   Action Code
9/6/2017 7:54   9/6/2017 8:07   WO Cancelled
9/7/2017 1:12   9/7/2017 2:46   WO Cancelled
9/6/2017 17:32  9/6/2017 19:25  WO Cancelled
9/6/2017 18:32  9/6/2017 20:25  NVD + No Fault Found
```

Below is my Query, but I get Output as NA in MinutesDiff

```
library("sqldf")
sqldf("SELECT [Action.Code],
       ((julianday([WO.Close.Date]))-
(julianday([WO.Create.Date]))*24*60) as       MinuteDiff
       from Alarmdata
       Where [Action.Code] like '%WO Cancelled%'
       And MinutesDiff<=5
       ")
```

Note: Minutesdiff is a alias name for difference between 2 datetime columns
also, when I checked the typeof (date columns), it shows as Integer.

Kindly give me a solution in SQLlite Query.

Comment: `9/6/2017 8:07` <-- this date format is NOT compatible with `julianday`.  You need this format: `2017-09-06 08:07:00` ... providing a query would be very involved and you would be better off fixing your date data.

Comment: Thanks Tim..I have changed the format of Date columns, as suggested by you.. Below is the Query and it woks fine. sqldf("SELECT [Action.Code],
       CAST((Julianday([WO.Close.Date]) - Julianday([WO.Create.Date]))*24*60 As Integer) as MinuteDiff
       from Alarmdata
       Where [Action.Code] like '%WO Cancelled%'")

Comment: This smells funny to me.  Update.your question with the latest data and we can from there.